# JestJS - Trying to Mock Async Await in Node JS Tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, jestjs

I am attempting to use Jest for my Node Js Test (specifically AWS's Lambda) but I am having difficulty mocking async await functionality.

I am using babel-jest and jest-cli. Below are my modules. **I am getting to the first console.log, but the second console.log returns undefined and my test crash.**

**Any ideas on how to implement this?**

Below is my module:

```
import {callAnotherFunction} from '../../../utils';

  export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  const {emailAddress, emailType} = event.body;
  console.log("**** GETTING HERE = 1")
  const sub = await callAnotherFunction(emailAddress, emailType);
  console.log("**** Not GETTING HERE = 2", sub) // **returns undefined**

  // do something else here
  callback(null, {success: true, returnValue: sub})

}
```

My Test

```
import testData from '../data.js';
import { handler } from '../src/index.js';
jest.mock('../../../utils');

beforeAll(() => {
  const callAnotherLambdaFunction= jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({success: true}));
});

describe('>>> SEND EMAIL LAMBDA', () => {
  test('returns a good value', done => {
    function callback(dataTest123) {
      expect(dataTest123).toBe({success: true, returnValue: sub);
      done();
    }

    handler(testData, null, callback);
  },10000);
})
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be careful about somethings below:

- Import your `utils` as a module then mock `callAnotherLambdaFunction`
  function
- Mock return value of `callAnotherLambdaFunction` with `Resolve` and `Reject` case
  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue

This is my example:

```
import testData from '../data.js';
import { handler } from '../src/index.js';
import * as Utils from '../../../utils'


jest.mock('../../../utils');
beforeAll(() => {
  Utils.callAnotherLambdaFunction = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('test');
});

describe('>>> SEND EMAIL LAMBDA', () => {
  it('should return a good value', async () => {
    const callback = jest.fn()
    await handler(testData, null, callback);
    expect(callback).toBeCalledWith(null, {success: true, returnValue: 'test'})
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`jest.mock('../../../utils');` is fine, But you are not actually mocking the implementation, you have to implement the behaviour yourself.

So you need to add

```
import { callAnotherFunction } from '../../../utils';

callAnotherFunction.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('someValue'));

test('test' , done => {
  const testData = {
    body: {
      emailAddress: 'email',
      emailType: 'type'
    }
  };

  function callback(dataTest123) {
    expect(dataTest123).toBe({success: true, returnValue: 'someValue');
    done();
  }

  handler(testData, null, callback);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I tried that and got the following error: Test suite failed to run.  TypeError: _callAnotherLambdaFunction2.default.mockImplementation is not a function

Comment: your function should be `callAnotherFunction` because that's the function you're trying to mock. Not sure what `callAnotherLambdaFunction` is, I don't see that in the actual file

Comment: Yes, that was a typo on my part in this boiled down example. In the real test, the function is the same name everywhere

Comment: `error mockImplementation is not a function`